# Can we integrate the office Communicator in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, content-query-web-part, office-integration

Would you please help me if  can we integrate the office communicator in sharepoint 2010 as live chat ??

or any link buttonn to open the office communicator user windows chatting ??

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

By default, Person list column has MS Office communicator presence indicator as activex control.

If you want to add  the same presence indicator to a custom link on SharePoint Page, you can use NameCtrl activeX control. For details, check here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455335.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look att Office Communicators API and SDK. It contains usefull documentation and code examples for integrating Communicator with other systems.

[API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/bb758719%28v=office.12%29.aspx), [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10176)